# Why can't mapToInt be used with collect(toList())?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I wrote this code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        List<String> a = Arrays.asList("One", "Two", "three");
        List<Integer> lengths = a.stream().mapToInt(String::length).collect(Collectors.toList());

    }
}
```

but it doesn't want to compile, saying:

```
Error:(8, 68) java: method collect in interface java.util.stream.IntStream cannot be applied to given types;
  required: java.util.function.Supplier<R>,java.util.function.ObjIntConsumer<R>,java.util.function.BiConsumer<R,R>
  found: java.util.stream.Collector<java.lang.Object,capture#1 of ?,java.util.List<java.lang.Object>>
  reason: cannot infer type-variable(s) R
    (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
```

What's happening here? Why the limitation? If you use map. Instead of mapToInt, it works fine.

Comment: In case it helps Google find this, the error message I get from trying this now is `"The method collect(Supplier<R>, ObjIntConsumer<R>, BiConsumer<R,R>) in the type IntStream is not applicable for the arguments (Collector<Object,?,List<Object>>)"`.

Comment: Try this : a.stream().map(String::length).collect(Collectors.toList());

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`mapToInt` produces an `IntStream`, which doesn't have `collect` method taking a single `Collector` argument.

Since the end result is a `List<Integer>`, you don't have to transform the `Stream` to an `IntStream`:

```
List<Integer> lengths = a.stream().map(String::length).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Transforming the `Stream` to an `IntStream` would make sense if you want to collect the elements of the `Stream` to an primitive array:

```
int[] lengths = a.stream().mapToInt(String::length).toArray();
```

If you want to transform to an `IntStream` and still use the `collect` method, you can write the following (which is less recommended):

```
List<Integer> lengths = 
    a.stream()
     .mapToInt(String::length)
     .collect(ArrayList::new, ArrayList::add, ArrayList::addAll);
```

Comment: simple way `a.stream().mapToInt(String::length).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: @HadiJ how is it simpler than just changing `mapToInt` to `map` and not having to call `boxed()`?

Comment: I mean instead of this `a.stream()
     .mapToInt(String::length)
     .collect(ArrayList::new, ArrayList::add, ArrayList::addAll);`

Comment: @HadiJ I was just demonstrating how to use `collect` on an `IntStream`. If you call `boxed()`, you are no longer using an `IntStream`, so you might as well not map to an `IntStream` in the first place, as mentioned at the beginning of my answer.

Comment: There might be a point in using `boxed()` if you need a `List<Long>` or `List<Double>`: `List<Long> lengths = a.stream().mapToLong(String::length).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());`

Answer (score 7):

There is a simple way to transform IntStream to Stream. Add `boxed()` as an intermediate operation and you will be able to use `collect()` as a terminal operation.

```
List<Integer> lengths = a.stream().mapToInt(String::length).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 2):

After `.mapToInt` you got an `IntStream`.

The `collect` definition for this stream is:

```
<R> R collect(Supplier<R> supplier,
              ObjIntConsumer<R> accumulator,
              BiConsumer<R, R> combiner);
```

Hence you cannot simply do `toList()` here.